# Can I Put 2D GIF Image on 3D Object

Tags: faces

Is there any way to put 2D GIF Image on a 3D Object? For example, I have a box. The box has 6 Faces. Can I put 2D gif on one of the box faces?

Comment: Also known as a decal.  Try a search using decal.

Comment: I don't know about GIFs, but JPG and PNG will work.

Comment: @batFINGER - thx, I'd double upvote your comment if I could ... was driving me nuts attempting to do this ... until you posted the word "decal". For anyone else, batFinger mentions 'shrink wrapping' here (http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-204348.html) which is exactly what I needed to do.

Comment: There is no support for gif in blender. The image has to be converted to a different format (jpg, tiff, png)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if animated gifs are supported, but videos can be used as color inputs.
You can see more about video textures here:
https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/video.html

in order to make the video appear on only one face of the box the best way would be to add one more material slot and assign a new material to that particular face.

Comment: gifs are not supported , both as an input and output format.